# phrase images from webpage coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, html-parsing

i need to get images from a webpage source.

i can use cfhttp method get and use htmleditformat() to read the html from that page, now i need to loop through the content to get all image url's(src)

can i use rematch() or refind() etc... and if yes how??

please help!!!!!

if im not clear i can try to clarify..

Comment: htmleditformat()? Don't think this function help you in any way in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function that will probably trip up on a lot of bad cases, but might work if you just need something quick and dirty.

```
<cffunction name="getSrcAttributes" access="public" output="No">
    <cfargument name="pageContents" required="Yes" type="string" default="" />

    <cfset var continueSearch = true />
    <cfset var cursor = "" />
    <cfset var startPos = 0 />
    <cfset var finalPos = 0 />
    <cfset var images = ArrayNew(1) />

    <cfloop condition="continueSearch eq true">
        <cfset cursor = REFindNoCase("src\=?[\""\']", arguments.pageContents, startPos, true) />

        <cfif cursor.pos[1] neq 0>
            <cfset startPos = (cursor.pos[1] + cursor.len[1]) />
            <cfset finalPos = REFindNoCase("[\""\'\s]", arguments.pageContents, startPos) />
            <cfset imgSrc = Mid(arguments.pageContents, startPos, finalPos - startPos) />

            <cfset ArrayAppend(images, imgSrc) />
        <cfelse>
            <cfset continueSearch = false />
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>

    <cfreturn images>
</cffunction>
```

Note: I can't verify at the moment that this code works.

Comment: Huh? *If* you're going the regex route (see Anthony's answer for why you shouldn't), you just want:
   
 `
 <!--- INFO: Grab things resembling src attributes: --->
 <cfset SrcMatches = rematch( 'src\s*=\s*(["'']?)((?!\1).)+' , InputText ) />
 
 <!--- INFO: Clean-up front of match (remove src=" part)  --->
 <cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#ArrayLen(SrcMatches)#">
  <cfset SrcMatches[i] = rereplace(SrcMatches[i],'src\s*=\s*["'']','')/>
 </cfloop>
 `

Comment: I had written this function a while back (before CF8, hence no REMatch) for, like I mention above, something quick and dirty.  I make no pretense that it is production code - obviously it doesn't check if src= is even in an img tag (or in a tag at all!) - but not all code has to be.

Comment: Peter Boughton: thanks for the code it seemes to pick up only one src attr. if you can modifty it to list all the src... i would appreciate that.
i added the #SrcMatches[i]#<br> in the loop assuming it will list all src found. 
 <cfset SrcMatches = rematch( 'src\s*=\s*(["'']?)((?!\1).)+' , InputText ) />
 <!--- INFO: Clean-up front of match (remove src=" part) ---> 
<cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#ArrayLen(SrcMatches)#"> 
<cfset SrcMatches[i] = rereplace(SrcMatches[i],'src\s*=\s*["'']','')/>
#SrcMatches[i]#<br>
 </cfloop>

Answer (score 3):

[It can be very difficult to reliably parse html with regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 1):

Use a browser and jQuery to 'query' out all the img tag from the DOM might be easier...

Comment: Or using this Java-based CSS selector library to do the querying:
http://github.com/chrsan/css-selectors/tree